# Using Contants from struts.xml as Annotation Value - Struts2 Java

Tags: java, struts2

I have a constant in struts.xml which sets the dateformat

```
<constant name="date.format" value="dd-MMM-yyyy" />
```

I want to use this constant as a annotation value in a bean class for a setter method like:

```
@JSON(format="date.format")               
public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {       
  this.endDate = endDate;
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: It's unclear what you asking.

Comment: I don't want to hardcode the dateFormat value in the annotation like @JSON(format="dd-MMM-yyyy). I want to read it from some external file

Answer (score 1):

The struts has an internal dependency injection, which you can use as:

```
public class Sample extends BaseActionSupport {

private String format;    

public String execute(){     
  //In you action
  System.out.println("The format is" + format);
}

@com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Inject("date.format")
public void setFormat(String format) {
    this.format = format;
}
```

The struts injects the `date.format` by calling `setFormat` and you can use it in action methods.